# Hive: Extracting text before a space or a period with regexp_extract()

Tags: regex, hive

How can I get the value of abc with regexp_extract()

Though abc appears twice in a row sometimes, yet the value is always unique.

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------+
|       my_str                             | value of abc |
+------------------------------------------+--------------+
|  che abc=666 ccc=42.csv                  |     666      |
|  che cbc=423 abc=666 cac=52.csv          |     666      | 
|  che ase=643 abc=666.csv                 |     666      |
|  che abc=666 gas=452 abc=666 fac=524.csv |     666      |
|  che abc=666 gbs=452 abc=666.csv         |     666      |
+------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try start with [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions). 
Find numbers after abc:

```
select regexp_extract(my_str, 'abc=(\\d+)', 1) from my_tbl
```

or find text before space

```
select regexp_extract(my_str, 'abc=([^ ])', 1) from my_tbl
```